# Execute code after data from asynchronous XMLHttpRequest is available

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I need to load a JSON file from the server once which I use later to populate content on the site. Loading the JSON file with an `XMLHttpRequest` should be asynchronous and can happen as soon as possible. Populating the content however requires the DOM to be loaded.

Now currently, I call `xhr.open('GET', 'records.json', false)` which makes the request synchronous. This was necessary for when it took more time to load and parse the JSON than it took the browser to load the DOM. When that happened (i.e. with a slow connection), the DOM would be loaded and the code in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener would be executed on `listData` which was still `undefined`. Bad.

How can I use an asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest` and at the same time execute my code on `DOMContentLoaded`? I want to execute my code as soon as `listData` is fully loaded (i.e. `JSON.parse()` is done) and the DOM is available. When both conditions are met, I’m good to go.

```
function thisFunctionIsCalledFromTheHtml() {
    // Get the JSON data by using a XML http request
    var listData;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // The request needs to be synchronous for now because on slow connections the DOM is ready
    // before it fetches everything from the json file
    xhr.open('GET', 'records.json', false);
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
              listData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          } else {
              console.error('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
          }
      }
    });
    xhr.addEventListener("error", function() {
      console.error('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
    });
    xhr.send(null);

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var placeholderKeys = [];
        for (var key in listData) {
            var value = listData[key];
            placeholderKeys = placeholderKeys.concat(value.title, value.abbr, value.keywords);
        }

        var filterInput = document.getElementById('input-id');
        filterInput.placeholder = placeholderKeys[
            Math.floor(Math.random() * placeholderKeys.length)
        ];
    });
}
```

Comment: no need for `DOMContentLoaded` if you make sure this function gets called from script tag placed after the element

Comment: @charlietfl But I don't want to wait with loading the JSON until after the DOM has loaded. That should happen as soon as possible.

Comment: Alternative is return a  promise and put promise callback in `DOMContentLoaded`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a promise along with your async get request and attache the successful returned data to something that will be available inside the `DOMContentLoaded` callback, in which you can repetitively check if the data has been assigned.

```js
let myData;

let doAsyncOperation = (param) => {
  if ( window.Promise ) {
    let promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

      // Do your async request here...
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        // resolve the promise with successfully returned data from get req.
        resolve(`Hello ${param}`)
      }, 1000);

      // reject the promise if your request returns an error
      if (typeof param !== "string") reject("param must be a string");

    })
    return promise;
  } else {
   console.log("Sorry no promise for you, use a fallback ")
  }
} 

doAsyncOperation("Foo !").then(
  // on success do something with your data.
  (data) =>  myData = data,
  (err) => console.log(err)
);

// Inside DOMContentLoaded callback check if myData is available.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
  let loop = () => {
   (myData) ? console.log(myData) : window.setTimeout(loop, 100);
  };
  loop();
});
```

Comment: Took me a while to be able to understand the syntax of arrow functions. Out of simplicity I wouldn’t use these in answers unrelated to arrow functions.

The approach itself works, of course. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the arrow function overload, just trying to get used to the latest features and use same all the time, besides that i just love the syntax. ;)

Comment: I was just looking at `(data) => myData = data` for two minutes and really had no idea what that was. Oh, well.

Comment: This one could actually be even more simplified to `data => myData = data` if there is only one argument you don't even need the brackets. I know this is really weird at first, but i kind of got the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to wait for several asynchronous events, my personal approach is usually something along these lines:

```
const EVENT0 = 0x1;
const EVENT1 = 0x2;
const ALL_READY = 0x3;

var ready = 0;
init();

function init() {
  asyncRequest0();
  asyncRequest1();

  var waitFunc;

  (waitFunc = function() {
    if(ready == ALL_READY) {
      goOn();
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(waitFunc, 10);
    }
  })();
}

function goOn() {
  console.log('Here we go!');
}

function asyncRequest0() {
  // some callback will do:
  ready |= EVENT0;
}

function asyncRequest1() {
  // some callback will do:
  ready |= EVENT1;
}
```

So basically, each asynchronous event will set a bit in the 'ready' variable once its job is completed. The waitFunc() function will patiently wait for all events to be completed (no matter in which order) and call the goOn() function.

Now, applied to your code:

```
const DOM_READY = 0x1;
const XHR_READY = 0x2;
const ALL_READY = 0x3;

var ready = 0;
var listData;

init();

function init() {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    ready |= DOM_READY;
  });

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'records.json', false);
  xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        listData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      } else {
        listData = false;
        console.error('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
      }
      ready |= XHR_READY;
    }
  });
  xhr.addEventListener("error", function() {
    listData = false;
    ready |= XHR_READY;
    console.error('Error: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + xhr.statusText);
  });
  xhr.send(null);

  var waitFunc;

  (waitFunc = function() {
    if (ready == ALL_READY) {
      goOn();
    } else {
      setTimeout(waitFunc, 10);
    }
  })();
}

function goOn() {
  console.log('Here we go!');
  // do something with listData
}
```

You don't really need a bitmask here for just 2 events, but it's a convenient way to test several events at once.

Comment: This approach works. What I don't underatand is why you set `listData` to `false` when it's not available. Why not leave it undefined?

Comment: @kleinfreund You definitely can leave it undefined just as well. (I'm usually setting 'faulty' results to 'false', but there's no particular reason to do so.)